# Props Parent component to a parent - child component

Tags: reactjs

How can I can call a function that is in the parent component (App) from a child component (Card)?

Card component renders one item (**CHILD**)

```
const Card = (props) => {
  return (
    <div style={{margin: '1em'}}>
      <img alt="Profile" width="75" src={props.avatar_url} />
      <div style={{display: 'inline-block', marginLeft: 10}}>
        <div style={{fontSize: '1.25em', fontWeight: 'bold'}}> 
            {props.name}
        </div>
        <div>{props.company}</div>
        <button
          //when I click here should trigger App's delete func who deletes the select item.  
          onClick = { () => alert()}
          className="btn btn-danger btn-sm">Delete</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

CardList component renders a list of item (**CHILD-PARENT**)

```
const CardList = (props) => {
    return (
  //Props.nameProp = Value {...Card} spred operator
    <div> 
        {props.cards.map(card => <Card key={card.id} {...card} />)}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Parent component:

```
class App extends React.Component {
    state = {
    cards: [
    ]
  };

  addNewCard = (cardInfo) => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
        cards: prevState.cards.concat(cardInfo)
    }))
  };

  deleteCard = (selectedCard) => {
      this.setState(prevState => ({
        //array.filter creates a new array with elements who pass the foo
        cards: prevState.cards.filter(card => card !== selectedCard)
      }));
  }

    render(){
    const {
      cards,
    } = this.state;
    return(
        <div className="container" style={{marginTop: 15}}>
        <Form onSubmit={this.addNewCard} />        
        <div className="container" style={{padding: 20}}>
          {
            cards.length > 0 ? 
            <CardList cards={cards} />
            :
            <p>Your list is empty</p>
          }
        </div>          
        </div>
    );      
  }
}
```

**EXPLANATION**

I want to delete a item who is in the state list but that list is in the parent component, how can I do that?

Comment: You can pass down the `deleteCard` as props to `CardList`, and from `CardList` to `Card` and call it there.

Comment: It worked! thanks you very much! . I just have to consider when I'm gonna use a func which is pass through props I have to use () at the end but when I pass to a component isn't necesary to use ().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass down the `deleteCard` method as a prop to `CardList`, and from `CardList` to each `Card` component and call it there.

**Example**

```js
const Card = props => (
  <button onClick={() => props.deleteCard(props.card)}>{props.card}</button>
);

const CardList = props => (
  <div>
    {props.cards.map(card => (
      <Card card={card} deleteCard={props.deleteCard} />
    ))}
  </div>
);

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    cards: [1, 2, 3]
  };

  deleteCard = card => {
    this.setState(({ cards }) => ({
      cards: cards.filter(element => element !== card)
    }));
  };
  
  render() {
    const { cards } = this.state;
    return <CardList cards={cards} deleteCard={this.deleteCard} />;
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```